# SERP Google - Mobile URL in incognito and normal URL on Desktop

Tags: google, url, search-results, incognito

Something strange is shown in Google SERP. My website have a desktop version and mobile version with a /m/ in URL that differ them. The problem or strange behavior i see is that:

> When i search for Brand name: **xxx** *(example)*

- *Google Chrome:* **Incognito** shows url: xxx.com/m/
- *Google Chrome:* **Non-incognito** shows url: xxx.com

Why is that?

Comment: Any one know seen this kind of behavior before?

Answer (score 1):

- Incognito follows the general mobile first paradigm - thats why it displays the mobile version,
- Non-Incognito uses personalization, it knows, that you use a desktop browser and delivers desktop version

Comment: Where can i read about your first point? I cannot find anything saying that Incognito follows "Mobile First" Paradigm? Incognito does not know if it is a desktop or mobile?